# Percent Change In Groupby Object by Group

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

I need some help with pandas groupby.  Is there a way to run a lambda (or equivalent) to each group in a pandas groupby?  See example below.  I'd like to add a percent change from previous year to a column to the right in this groupby.  I tried several methods, but they all seem to ignore starting over at the new 'Item' groups.

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series(['Oranges', 'Apples', 'Other Fruits', 'Oranges', 'Apples', 'Other Fruits', 'Oranges', 'Apples', 'Other Fruits'])
y = pd.Series([2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018])
z = pd.Series([12, 15, 9, 14, 15, 50, 32, 15, 12])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': x, 'Year':y, 'Values':z})
df=df.sort_values('Values', ascending=False) 
df.groupby(['Item', 'Year']).sum()
#How do I get Percent % Values for each group as a new column right of 'Values'
```

I'm expecting the following:

[image: Results Expected]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `GroupBy` + `apply` with `pct_change`:

```
# Sort DataFrame before grouping.
df = df.sort_values(['Item', 'Year']).reset_index(drop=True)
# Group on keys and call `pct_change` inside `apply`.
df['Change'] = df.groupby('Item', sort=False)['Values'].apply(
     lambda x: x.pct_change()).to_numpy()

df
           Item  Year  Values    Change
0        Apples  2016      15       NaN
1        Apples  2017      15  0.000000
2        Apples  2018      15  0.000000
3       Oranges  2016      12       NaN
4       Oranges  2017      14  0.166667
5       Oranges  2018      32  1.285714
6  Other Fruits  2016       9       NaN
7  Other Fruits  2017      50  4.555556
8  Other Fruits  2018      12 -0.760000
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I guess I would then concat the new series to the df?  I wonder if I could do this in an aggfunc on the first groupby.

Comment: @TylerRussell The result can be assigned back with `df['Change'] = df.sort_values('Year').groupby('Item')['Values'].pct_change()` as shown in the commented out code.

Comment: Results for this method are not lining up.  If I run a df.sort_values('Item') or df.sort_values(['Item', 'Year']) with the new column, the percent change for Year 2 of Apples is -.7000, which should be a 0.

Comment: @TylerRussell I think the issue is that GroupBy was sorting the data. What about now?

Comment: See my edit above.  Thanks for your assistance on this.  The new code is doing the same thing for me.

Comment: @TylerRussell Okay thanks, hopefully it should be fixed now.

Comment: Very close.  The Change values are right, but the names on the left should be sorted still by Item/Year.

Comment: The only issue is if the "Values" is negative then it doesn't take the absolute value. Try the same example with Apples with "Values" like -15, -10, -5 for three years. There is a bug in pct_change API.

Comment: I found this hack somewhere to handle negative values. Ideally pct_change implementation should consider abs(val) while calculating.                      df.groupby(['Item], sort=False)['Values'].pct_change()*np.sign(df['Values'].shift(periods=1))